# deleting entity in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have this entity :

```
public class User 
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public Image Photo { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Right> Rights { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Rights = new List<Right>();
    }        
}
```

and I am trying to delete it this way :

```
public void Delete(User user)
        {
            using (var db = new  MyDbContext)
            {
                db.Rights.RemoveRange(user.Rights);
                db.Users.Remove(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

in my context Image and Right are entities too. In this delete I want the rights of the user to be deleted, the user itself to be deleted, but the Image should stay in the database.

But when executing following exception is thrown:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

Im using EF 6.

Have you any idea how to solve this problem?
thank you

Comment: Is that really the code that throws the error? From the error message, it looks as you are trying to do something after you've disposed the context.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068726/system-objectdisposedexception

Comment: Oh, youre right, the context of the entity is already disposed :) but how can I delete an entity which was loaded from a different context then? Is it a good practice to keep reference on that context within the entity ?

Comment: You can attach the entity to the new context.

Answer (score 1):

I'll always do this.

```
var db = new DatabaseEntities();
var item = db.TableName.Where(x=>x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
db.TableName.Remove(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `ObjectContext` of `user` may be disposed already. So you need to re-read the object to delete (`userToDelete`).

```
public void Delete(User user)
{
  using (var db = new MyDbContext)
  {
     User userToDelete = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();
     if(userToDelete != null) {
       db.Rights.RemoveRange(user.Rights);
       db.Users.Remove(user);
       db.SaveChanges();
     }
  }
}
```