# How do you add to an ICollection list and save it to a database without gettingan object disposed exception? (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, collections

Lets say we have a class like this:

```
public class SampleClass
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ScoreData> ScoreData{ get; set; }
}
```

And another class like this:

```
public class ScoreData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int subSectionScore {get; set;}

    public int SampleClassID { get; set; }
    public virtual SampleClass SampleClass { get; set; }
}
```

Why does this throw an object disposed exception and how can it be fixed?

```
internal static void CalculatesubSectionScores(ref List<SampleClass> sampleClassData)
{

    foreach (var item in sampleClassData)
    {
        item.ScoreData= new List<ScoreData>();

        /* code in second foreach accesses another objects item to 
           use for each sub sections calculations*/

        foreach ()
        {
           var scoringData = new ScoreData();
           var score = 0.0;
           scoringData.subSectionScore = score;

           item.ScoreData.Add(scoringData);
        }
    }
```

I've removed most of the logic from this class just to focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: use the debugger.. for starters.. step through the code and see what the value of `sampleClassData` is before hitting the foreach line of code.. also I am currious as to why you are passing `ref of sampleClassData`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ObjectDisposedException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068726/system-objectdisposedexception)

Comment: @MethodMan I've done this and it has the correct values for each of of the sampleClassData properties but ScoreData threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'.

Also the reason I pass a ref is so that when I exit that method I have a list of objects that each have a list of the ScoreData object. I thought that if I didn't reference, then the list would not get added to my SampleCass object.

Comment: is your calling code wrapped in a `using(){}` block?

Comment: doesn't make any sense .. when all you have to do is change the method signature to return a List<Class> object that you have created.. perhaps you need to refactor that method to return a `List<SampleClass>`

Comment: @prospector, no it isn't. I think there's something I don't understand there. I'm new to entity framework.

Comment: @MethodMan, the sample class actually has more properties that have already been assigned. I just didn't list them here because they weren't necessary to the problem at hand.

Comment: and.. the problem and or issue with that is..??

Comment: @MethodMan so you're suggesting that I just pass in the list and return that same list after the methods done executing?

Comment: Please show the exact code that throws the exception, indicating the line where it happens. It's OK that you try to slim down the code for brevity, but if you don't fully understand what happens it's too easy to remove parts you don't realize are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ScoreData` before adding to it

```
internal static void CalculatesubSectionScores(ref List<SampleClass> sampleClassData)
{

    foreach (var item in sampleClassData)
    {
        item.ScoreData= new List<ScoreData>();

        /* code in second foreach accesses another objects item to 
           use for each sub sections calculations*/

        item.ScoreData = new List<ScoreData>();  // Add This Line

        foreach ()
        {
           var scoringData = new ScoreData();
           var score = 0.0;
           scoringData.subSectionScore = score;

           item.ScoreData.Add(scoringData);
        }
    }
}
```