# System.objectdisposed exception occur when I press back button in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am  getting 'System.objectdisposed exception' when I navigate from one page to another page and with out loading that navigated page when I press back button getting 'System.objectdisposed exception' exception. I am getting this exception when I run xamarin android project, In xamarin ios is working fine. I didn't find what the root cause of this exception. Is any one have any idea about this, Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ObjectDisposedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068726/system-objectdisposedexception)

Comment: Could you please share codes so can we try to reproduce this issue?