# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Android.Widget.ListView' only in case of Android

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

I am using a FlowListView and Whenever i press back button it takes me to Android Home, Then again i open my app and again i press back button (repeat the steps 3-4 times) it gives me an Error: 
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Android.Widget.ListView'.
I tried using these two lines but error is still there.

```
<x:Arguments>                
  <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
</x:Arguments>

<controls:FlowListView CachingStrategy = "RecycleElement"
Factor=1}">
```

The error should not be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ObjectDisposedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068726/system-objectdisposedexception)

Comment: Its not actually, I am using Xamarin and this issue comes only in Android

Comment: I am having the same issue from some time until now on XF  5.0.0.2012 but cannot find the scenario to reproduce, it happens from time to time to my users. I opened this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14194) on the XF github repo but cannot provide a reproductible sample